# Radio Button inside Recyclerview is not working properly in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-recyclerview, radio-button

```
Adapter Class
--------------

class FilterByDataAdapter(
    val filterByData: (ArrayList<String>) -> Unit, val filterByDataRadioBtn: (String) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<FilterByDataAdapter.FilterByDataViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var itemFilterByListBinding: ItemFilterByListBinding
    private lateinit var filerByDataList: ArrayList<FilterByItemDataModel>
    private lateinit var filterByName: String

    var filteredData: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FilterByDataViewHolder {
        itemFilterByListBinding =
            ItemFilterByListBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)

        return FilterByDataViewHolder(itemFilterByListBinding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FilterByDataViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val filterByDataItem = filerByDataList[position]
        filterByDataItem.let {
            holder.apply {
                this.bindFilterByData(it, filterByName)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return filerByDataList.size
    }

    fun setFilterByDataList(
        filterByTimeList: ArrayList<FilterByItemDataModel>, filterName: String
    ) {
        filerByDataList = filterByTimeList
        filterByName = filterName
    }

    inner class FilterByDataViewHolder(itemFilterByListBinding: ItemFilterByListBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemFilterByListBinding.root) {
        fun bindFilterByData(filterByItemDataModel: FilterByItemDataModel, filterByName: String) {
            itemFilterByListBinding.filterItemTxt.text = filterByItemDataModel.itemName

            validateButtonChecked(filterByName, filterByItemDataModel)
        }

        private fun validateButtonChecked(
            filterByName: String, filterByItemDataModel: FilterByItemDataModel
        ) {
            when (filterByName) {
                TIME -> {
                    itemFilterByListBinding.filterRadioGroup.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    itemFilterByListBinding.filterRadioBtn.isChecked = filterByItemDataModel.isChecked

                    itemFilterByListBinding.filterRadioBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->

                    }
                }

                STATUS, VALIDITY -> {
                    itemFilterByListBinding.filterCheckBoxBtn.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                    itemFilterByListBinding.filterCheckBoxBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
                        filteredData = Utils.processCheckBoxItems(
                            filterByName, isChecked, filterByItemDataModel.itemName.toString()
                        )
                        filterByData.invoke(filteredData)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Fragment Class
---------------

class FilterByBottomSheetDialog(private val onShowResultClick: (ArrayList<String>) -> Unit) :
    BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var dialogFilterLayoutBinding: DialogFilterLayoutBinding

    private lateinit var filterByData: ArrayList<FilterByItemDataModel>
    private lateinit var filterName: String

    private val filterByItemAdapter by lazy {
        FilterByDataAdapter(
            { action -> actionOnFilterByClick(action) },
            { item -> actionOnFilterByRadioBtnClick(item) })
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        dialogFilterLayoutBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(context), R.layout.dialog_filter_layout, null, false
        )
       return dialogFilterLayoutBinding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        if (::filterByData.isInitialized) {
            setFilterByDataRecyclerView(filterByData, filterName)
        }
    }

    private fun setFilterByDataRecyclerView(
        filterByTimeList: ArrayList<FilterByItemDataModel>, filterName: String
    ) {
        filterByItemAdapter.setFilterByDataList(getFilterByTimeList(), filterName)
        dialogFilterLayoutBinding.filterItemRecyclerView.adapter = filterByItemAdapter
    }

    fun getFilterByTimeList(): ArrayList<FilterByItemDataModel> {
        val timeArrayList = ArrayList<FilterByItemDataModel>()
        val data = arrayListOf("week", "month", "year")

        for (i in data.indices) {
            timeArrayList.add(
                FilterByItemDataModel(
                    itemName = data[i],
                    isChecked = false
                )
            )
        }

        return timeArrayList
    }

}

list item xml
---------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="filterItemName"
            type="com.xxx.xxxxx.datamodel.FilterByItemDataModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/filter_item_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/txt_black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@color/txt_light_grey"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/filter_item_txt" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/filter_radio_group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                android:id="@+id/filter_radio_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </RadioGroup>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Hi All,
I am facing an issue with checking and unchecking of radio button in recycler view. I am showing data from an arraylist and displaying it in recyclerview. But when I am trying to select, all selected items are selected instead of deselecting the last checked item.

Any Help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks for all in advance.
Here's my code for the reference,

Answer (score 0):

The whole logic of updating your list would be indicated to be done in a viewmodel and by using differ in your adapter those changes will happen without any headache, so

you trigger a selection of an item -> update the list in the viewmodel, then you submit the modified list and it's observed then list gets updated, try it and if you need any help with it just post your progress and happy to help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In other to make your answer clearer, adding a sample mockup code would let the OP understand your point. It makes the OP easier to follow

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related to the way you're handling the checked state of radio buttons in your `FilterByDataAdapter`.

You can maintain a variable to track the currently selected position and update it when a new item is selected. Here's how you can modify your `FilterByDataAdapter`:

```
class FilterByDataAdapter(
    val filterByData: (ArrayList<String>) -> Unit, 
    val filterByDataRadioBtn: (String) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<FilterByDataAdapter.FilterByDataViewHolder>() {

    // ... (other existing code)

    private var selectedPosition: Int = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FilterByDataViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val filterByDataItem = filerByDataList[position]
        filterByDataItem.let {
            holder.apply {
                this.bindFilterByData(it, filterByName, position)
            }
        }
    }

    inner class FilterByDataViewHolder(itemFilterByListBinding: ItemFilterByListBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemFilterByListBinding.root) {

        fun bindFilterByData(
            filterByItemDataModel: FilterByItemDataModel,
            filterByName: String,
            position: Int
        ) {
            // ... (other existing code)

            when (filterByName) {
                TIME -> {
                    // ... (other existing code)

                    itemFilterByListBinding.filterRadioBtn.isChecked =
                        position == selectedPosition

                    itemFilterByListBinding.filterRadioBtn.setOnClickListener {
                        if (position != selectedPosition) {
                            // Clear the previous selection
                            notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition)
                            // Update the selected position
                            selectedPosition = position
                            // Update the UI for the newly selected item
                            notifyItemChanged(position)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                // ... (other existing code)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*This modification ensures that only one radio button is selected at a time within the `RadioGroup`. The `selectedPosition` variable is used to keep track of the currently selected position, and the `notifyItemChanged` method is used to update the UI accordingly.*